# Accessing private properties from outside

Tags: typescript, private

I faced a 'strange' behaviour in typescript:

```js
    class A {
        private _prop;

        public a() {
            let x = new A();
            x._prop
        }
    }
```

does not raise any exception, whereas I am accessing a private property from outside an object.

Does someone know:

- if it's a normal behaviour (I guess yes)
- where I can find some literature about this? I found it very confusing...

**edit**
I meant: the compiler does not show any exception, where as I access private property `_prop` from outside object x. I am not speaking about run time.

Comment: What private property are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior, you are in the same class context, which means you can access the private property even it is new instance.

Here is the C# equivalent of same behavior (valid)

```
public class A
{
    private int _prop;
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var x = new A();
        x._prop = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of private access is allowed in most languages. You can't access the privates of any other class, but you can access the privates of the current class, even if they are privates of another instance of the class.

Ex [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers):

> `private`: The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.

(no mention of whether the member must be accessed through `this`)